# Effectiveness of COVID-19 "booster" (typically the third shot) when being administered after a long time following the initial two doses

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, effectiveness

In layman's terms, "booster" seems to mean to enhance upon the initial vaccination dose(s). [This article](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2021-11-26/boosters-prevent-covid-better-after-six-month-wait-doctors-say) suggests administering it after about six months.

I am considering having the third shot after almost one year after the initial two doses and I am wondering about the third shot effectiveness after such a long time. Or maybe I should consider having a complete scheme fourth shot is not allowed yet, but we are getting closer) to reach a decent effectiveness.

Comment: Who are these "many folks" you're referring to? Just random people ignoring the health authorities and doing what they want? And where is your prior research? You're not new here, you know that's required.